# Issue Removing Google Maps Drawing Manager Overlay

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Edit: I have tried to include a snippet, but it does not show the actual issue as it just says script error (though in the dev console, it shows the error I have mentioned).

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Add Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>

  <style>
  
 #map {
    height: 100%;
  }

  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <!--The div element for the map -->
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- 
      The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML
      document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
      and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises
      with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader.
      -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAksEGQLj6SwcxTQva_Camj-O1skokx-rQ&callback=initMap&v=weekly&libraries=drawing,geometry"
      defer
    ></script>
    
    <script>
    let map, infoWindow;
const locationButton = document.createElement("button");
const clearButton = document.createElement("button");
const drawGeofenceButton = document.createElement("button");

let tri = null;
var _myPolygon; // global variable to store the polygon instance



var selectedShape;
//so we don't create duplicates
let drawingManager;

function initMap() {

  var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
  //initialize the map
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 31.800, lng: -95.600 },
    zoom: 6,
  });

  //info window that displays the coordinates we are using.
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


  locationButton.textContent = "Pan to Current Location";
  locationButton.classList.add("custom-map-control-button");

  clearButton.textContent = "Clear Geofence";
  clearButton.classList.add("custom-map-control-button");

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(locationButton);

  drawGeofenceButton.textContent = "Draw Geofence";
  drawGeofenceButton.classList.add("custom-map-control-button");
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(drawGeofenceButton);

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(clearButton);
    
  setListeners();   

}


function setListeners(){
  
 //add option inside to create button listener for draw geofence button.
 drawGeofenceButton.addEventListener("click", () =>{

    //ensure we can get rid of the old geofence
        if(tri != null && tri != undefined){
            tri.setMap(null);
        }
                       
                      
        //to do: add button to clear all paths
        //ensure we don't recreate
        if(drawingManager != null && drawingManager != undefined){
            drawingManager = null;
        } 
            drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
                drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                drawingControl: true,
                drawingControlOptions: {
                    drawingModes: [
                        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                    ]
                },
                circleOptions: {
                    fillColor: '#FF0000',
                    fillOpacity: 0.6,
                    strokeWeight: 3,
                    clickable: true,
                    editable: true,
                    zIndex: 1
                },
                polygonOptions: {
                    fillColor: '#FF0000',
                    fillOpacity: 0.6,
                    strokeWeight: 3,
                    clickable: true,
                    editable: true,
                    zIndex: 1
                    },
                                      
                });
            drawingManager.setMap(map);

       
        });
        
        google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
    _myPolygon = e.overlay;
});

    locationButton.addEventListener("click", () => {


        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
         
          console.log('Getting current position...');
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
             let pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
              }
              //pos.lat = position.coords.latitude;
              //pos.lng = position.coords.longitude;
    
              console.log('Adding new marker...');
              const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pos,
                    map: map,
                    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/target.png",
                  });
             // infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
             
              console.log('Pos.lat = ' + pos.lat);
              console.log('Pos.lng = ' + pos.lng);
              //infoWindow.setContent("Location found.");
              //infoWindow.open(map);
              console.log('Setting center of map.');
              map.setCenter(pos);
            
                    //instantiate polygon to be based on the coordinates provided by the current location.
            // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
            const coords = [
              { lat: (pos.lat - 0.003752),  lng: (pos.lng - 0.003752)},
              { lat: (pos.lat - 0.003752), lng: (pos.lng + 0.003752) },
              { lat: (pos.lat + 0.003752), lng: (pos.lng + 0.003752)},
            ];
    
              //build the geofence
              tri = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: coords,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 3,
                fillColor: "#FF0000",
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                editable: true
              });
    
    
              //add the geofence to map
              tri.setMap(map);
              console.log('Set geofence....');
      
              // Add a listener for the click event.
              tri.addListener("click", showArrays);
    
    
              infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            
            },
            () => {
              handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            }
          );
    
    
           // setGeoFence(map, coords);
        
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      });


    

  /**
   * Use this event listener to clear the current geofence options.
   */
  clearButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    deleteSelectedShape();

});



}


/**
 * Based on Google Maps API code for a polygon
 * @param {} event 
 */
function showArrays(event) {
  // Since this polygon has only one path, we can call getPath() to return the
  // MVCArray of LatLngs.
  // @ts-ignore
  const polygon = this;
  const vertices = polygon.getPath();
  let contentString =
    "<b>Geofence Triangle polygon</b><br>" +
    "Clicked location: <br>" +
    event.latLng.lat() +
    "," +
    event.latLng.lng() +
    "<br>";

  // Iterate over the vertices.
  for (let i = 0; i < vertices.getLength(); i++) {
    const xy = vertices.getAt(i);

    contentString +=
      "<br>" + "Coordinate " + i + ":<br>" + xy.lat() + "," + xy.lng();
  }

  // Replace the info window's content and position.
  infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
  infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
  infoWindow.open(map);
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(
    browserHasGeolocation
      ? "Error: The Geolocation service failed."
      : "Error: Your browser doesn't support geolocation."
  );
  infoWindow.open(map);
}


function clearSelection() {
    if (selectedShape) {
      selectedShape.setEditable(false);
      selectedShape = null;
    }
  }


  function setSelection(shape) {
    clearSelection();
    selectedShape = shape;
    shape.setEditable(true);
  }

  
  function deleteSelectedShape() {
    _myPolygon.setMap(null);
  }

window.initMap = initMap;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am developing a simple geofencing application in JavaScript using Google Maps API. I can create a geofence using the DrawingManager without issue, but am getting an error when trying to access the overlay. The only way that I am seeing I can access the overlay is by using this listener, which is throwing an error in the console (that I will attach as well). I need access to the overlay in order to remove the overlay or otherwise attach listeners to the object being clicked, which I cannot do because of this ongoing issue.

The listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
    _myPolygon = e.overlay;
});
```

The error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__e3_')
    at yba (js?key=AIzaSyAksEGQLj6SwcxTQva_Camj-O1skokx-rQ&callback=initMap&v=weekly&libraries=drawing,geometry:128:361)
    at new _.uf (js?key=AIzaSyAksEGQLj6SwcxTQva_Camj-O1skokx-rQ&callback=initMap&v=weekly&libraries=drawing,geometry:129:399)
    at _.L [as addListener] (js?key=AIzaSyAksEGQLj6SwcxTQva_Camj-O1skokx-rQ&callback=initMap&v=weekly&libraries=drawing,geometry:126:108)
    at setListeners (index_Local.js:192:23)
    at initMap (index_Local.js:53:3)
    at js?key=AIzaSyAksEGQLj6SwcxTQva_Camj-O1skokx-rQ&callback=initMap&v=weekly&libraries=drawing,geometry:245:146
    at js?key=AIzaSyAksEGQLj6SwcxTQva_Camj-O1skokx-rQ&callback=initMap&v=weekly&libraries=drawing,geometry:244:238
```

I am aware that a few of these helper methods aren't currently being used... until I can figure out why I am not able to access the overlay to remove it from the map, I really do not have use for testing their integration into the code.

This issue is preventing me accessing the overlay to clear it for redrawing, which is a significant hindrance. Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the drawing manager inside the `drawGeofenceButton.addEventListener`, but the line of code immediately after that function `google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager`, throws an error if `drawingManager` is undefined (or null).

Move that event listener definition inside the function that creates the `DrawingManager` so it isn't null when the event listener is created.

**updated code snippet:**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Add Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>

  <style>
  
 #map {
    height: 100%;
  }

  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <!--The div element for the map -->
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- 
      The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML
      document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
      and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises
      with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader.
      -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAksEGQLj6SwcxTQva_Camj-O1skokx-rQ&callback=initMap&v=weekly&libraries=drawing,geometry"
      defer
    ></script>
    
    <script>
    let map, infoWindow;
const locationButton = document.createElement("button");
const clearButton = document.createElement("button");
const drawGeofenceButton = document.createElement("button");

let tri = null;
var _myPolygon; // global variable to store the polygon instance



var selectedShape;
//so we don't create duplicates
let drawingManager;

function initMap() {

  var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
  //initialize the map
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 31.800, lng: -95.600 },
    zoom: 6,
  });

  //info window that displays the coordinates we are using.
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


  locationButton.textContent = "Pan to Current Location";
  locationButton.classList.add("custom-map-control-button");

  clearButton.textContent = "Clear Geofence";
  clearButton.classList.add("custom-map-control-button");

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(locationButton);

  drawGeofenceButton.textContent = "Draw Geofence";
  drawGeofenceButton.classList.add("custom-map-control-button");
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(drawGeofenceButton);

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(clearButton);
    
  setListeners();   

}


function setListeners(){
  
 //add option inside to create button listener for draw geofence button.
 drawGeofenceButton.addEventListener("click", () =>{

    //ensure we can get rid of the old geofence
        if(tri != null && tri != undefined){
            tri.setMap(null);
        }
                       
                      
        //to do: add button to clear all paths
        //ensure we don't recreate
        if(drawingManager != null && drawingManager != undefined){
            drawingManager = null;
        } 
            drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
                drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                drawingControl: true,
                drawingControlOptions: {
                    drawingModes: [
                        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                    ]
                },
                circleOptions: {
                    fillColor: '#FF0000',
                    fillOpacity: 0.6,
                    strokeWeight: 3,
                    clickable: true,
                    editable: true,
                    zIndex: 1
                },
                polygonOptions: {
                    fillColor: '#FF0000',
                    fillOpacity: 0.6,
                    strokeWeight: 3,
                    clickable: true,
                    editable: true,
                    zIndex: 1
                    },
                                      
                });
            drawingManager.setMap(map);

           // only add the listener if drawingManager is not null
           google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
             _myPolygon = e.overlay;
           });       
        });
        


    locationButton.addEventListener("click", () => {


        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
         
          console.log('Getting current position...');
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
             let pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
              }
              //pos.lat = position.coords.latitude;
              //pos.lng = position.coords.longitude;
    
              console.log('Adding new marker...');
              const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: pos,
                    map: map,
                    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/target.png",
                  });
             // infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
             
              console.log('Pos.lat = ' + pos.lat);
              console.log('Pos.lng = ' + pos.lng);
              //infoWindow.setContent("Location found.");
              //infoWindow.open(map);
              console.log('Setting center of map.');
              map.setCenter(pos);
            
                    //instantiate polygon to be based on the coordinates provided by the current location.
            // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon.
            const coords = [
              { lat: (pos.lat - 0.003752),  lng: (pos.lng - 0.003752)},
              { lat: (pos.lat - 0.003752), lng: (pos.lng + 0.003752) },
              { lat: (pos.lat + 0.003752), lng: (pos.lng + 0.003752)},
            ];
    
              //build the geofence
              tri = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: coords,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 3,
                fillColor: "#FF0000",
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                editable: true
              });
    
    
              //add the geofence to map
              tri.setMap(map);
              console.log('Set geofence....');
      
              // Add a listener for the click event.
              tri.addListener("click", showArrays);
    
    
              infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            
            },
            () => {
              handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            }
          );
    
    
           // setGeoFence(map, coords);
        
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      });


    

  /**
   * Use this event listener to clear the current geofence options.
   */
  clearButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    deleteSelectedShape();

});



}


/**
 * Based on Google Maps API code for a polygon
 * @param {} event 
 */
function showArrays(event) {
  // Since this polygon has only one path, we can call getPath() to return the
  // MVCArray of LatLngs.
  // @ts-ignore
  const polygon = this;
  const vertices = polygon.getPath();
  let contentString =
    "<b>Geofence Triangle polygon</b><br>" +
    "Clicked location: <br>" +
    event.latLng.lat() +
    "," +
    event.latLng.lng() +
    "<br>";

  // Iterate over the vertices.
  for (let i = 0; i < vertices.getLength(); i++) {
    const xy = vertices.getAt(i);

    contentString +=
      "<br>" + "Coordinate " + i + ":<br>" + xy.lat() + "," + xy.lng();
  }

  // Replace the info window's content and position.
  infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
  infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
  infoWindow.open(map);
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(
    browserHasGeolocation
      ? "Error: The Geolocation service failed."
      : "Error: Your browser doesn't support geolocation."
  );
  infoWindow.open(map);
}


function clearSelection() {
    if (selectedShape) {
      selectedShape.setEditable(false);
      selectedShape = null;
    }
  }


  function setSelection(shape) {
    clearSelection();
    selectedShape = shape;
    shape.setEditable(true);
  }

  
  function deleteSelectedShape() {
    _myPolygon.setMap(null);
  }

window.initMap = initMap;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```